# Arrays of Objects, how to search for a word ?

Tags: c++

I am confuse on how to access the data in the ostream and istream operator. My task is to search for a certain last name. Here is my codes in one file

```
 // postlab.cpp 
//   this program implements a student database 
//   user can print, and search by 
//     lastname, email, area code, and city
//    
//   HINT to search by area code, use the
//    C++ string substring function, for example
//        string s = "hamburger";
//        cout<<s.substr(3,4);   // prints burg
//
//    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;


void get_stream(ifstream& ins);
int menu();                                      // print the menu of choicse
void print_list(int size, Student s[]);    // print the whole list
void ln_search(int size, Student s[]);     // search database for last name
void email_search(int size, Student s[]);  // search for an email address
void ac_search(int size, Student s[]);     // search for all in an area code
void city_search(int size, Student s[]);   // search for all in a city

int main( )
{
     int size, count, choice;

     ifstream ins;
     get_stream(ins);

     ins >> size;  // the first value in file is the number of records
     Student *dbase = new Student[size]; // to store student's data in 
                                         // student array      
     for (int k=0; k<size; k++){
        ins >> dbase[k];
        cout << dbase[k]<<endl;
     }

     // database read, now we process it
     do {
        choice = menu(); // display menu and input choice

        // process user choice
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                print_list(size,dbase);
                break;
            case 2:  
                ln_search(size,dbase);
                break;
        }
     } while (choice != 6);  // 6 is exit command


     return 0;
}


void get_stream(ifstream& ins)
{
    ins.open("student.txt");
    if(ins.fail())
    {
       cout << "Failed to open the input file. \n";
       exit(1);
    }
}

int menu()                                      // print the menu of choicse
{
    int choice;
    cout<<"Student Database Processor"<<endl;
    cout<<"Menu:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1 - Print All Students"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 - Search by Last Name"<<endl;
    cout<<"3 - Search by email address"<<endl;
    cout<<"4 - Print All Students with Requested Area Code"<<endl;
    cout<<"5 - Print All Students Living in Requested City"<<endl;
    cout<<"6 - Exit"<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}

void print_list(int size, Student s[])    // print the whole list
{
    cout << "Student database contain: " << endl; 
    for (int k = 1; k<size; k++)
      cout << k << "-" << s[k] << endl; 

    // write a for loop and print all students in s.
    // remember, s is an array, so, cout<<s[k]<<endl;

}

void ln_search(int size, Student s[])
{ 
  string ln; 
  cout << "Enter the last name: " << endl; 
  cin >> ln ; 
   for(int k = 0 ;k<size;k++){ 

       if(ln == s[k].lastname) 
        cout<< "Found"; 
        cout<<s[k] << endl; 
         // of the last name we entered
}

}
```

This is the second file

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
    //ctor
}


istream& operator>>(istream& ins, Student& s)
{   
    // this initial do-loop skips over any blank lines 
    //  in the file that may be separating data entries
    do{
        getline(ins, s.lastName);   
    } while(s.lastName.length()==0&& !ins.fail());

    getline(ins, s.firstName); // using getline allows multiple words per field
    getline(ins, s.email);
    getline(ins, s.address);
    getline(ins, s.city);
    getline(ins, s.state);
    getline(ins, s.zip);
    getline(ins, s.phone);
    return ins;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& outs, Student& s)
{
    outs<<"Student: "<<s.lastName<<" "<<s.firstName<<" "<<s.email<<endl;
    outs<<s.address<<" "<<s.city<<" "<<s.state<<" "<<s.zip<<endl;
    outs<<s.phone<<endl<<endl;
    return outs;
}
```

So here is my function to search the name so far :

```
  string ln; 
  cout << "Enter the last name: " << endl; 
  cin >> ln ; 
   for(int k = 0 ;k<size;k++){ 

       if(ln == s[k].lastname) 
        cout<< "Found"; 
        cout<<s[k] << endl; 
         // of the last name we entered
}

}
```

but it doesn't work, I don't understand how I can access the lastname on the istream operator on the first file?? Please help

Comment: *http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/* -- Not a good site to learn how to write proper C++ code.  Why are you not using `std::vector`?  Why are you not using `std::find_if` instead of writing a loop?  Etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a brace for the `if` so that it contains both of the print statements, assuming you just want to return in the case of "no students found with that name".

```
void ln_search(int size, Student s[]){
  string ln;
  cout << "Enter the last name: " << endl;
  cin >> ln;
  for(int k = 0; k<size; k++){
    if(ln == s[k].lastname){
      cout << "Found";
      cout << s[k] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

However, by the [Cpp Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r2-in-interfaces-use-raw-pointers-to-denote-individual-objects-only) you should be using a [Container Object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) instead.

```
void ln_search(deque<Student> students){
    string ln;
    cout << "Enter the last name: " << endl;
    cin  >> ln;
    for(auto student&:students)
        if(ln == student.lastname)
            cout << "Found"
                 << student
                 << endl;
}
```

PS: Your function will display multiple outputs in case of multiple students, and with you current `operator<<` definition that will probably look strange.